# Rename model terms in lm object for forecasting

Tags: r

I have regression models fitted on data that I then want to use for forecasting, but the column names in the training data and the forecast data are different. The typical approach would be to simply rename the columns so they are the same in both datasets. However, I'm wondering if there is also a way I can instead directly modify the names of the terms in the fitted lm object, so for example the term `x1` can be renamed to `x2` and then I can run `predict(model, data)` where `data` has a column called `x2` in it.

Comment: Another option is to specify a named list for the `newdata` argument in `predict`. For example, if your `model` has the formula `y ~ x1`, and you wish to evaluate it on `data`, using `x2` in place of `x1`, you would have `predict(model, newdata=list(x1=data$x2))`.

Comment: I agree with @nrussell that the easier way here is to change the names of newdata. The `lm` object keeps the variable names stored in many places though out the object. Changing them all is non trivial. You could also rename them at the time of fitting. Something like `lm(y~x2, transform(mydata, x2=x1))`